# Backup and Restore DHCP

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server

Today our Windows Server 2003 server is running DHCP to serve all clients with IP addresses.
We have installed a new Windows Server 2012 R2. Now i want to move the DHCP from the 2003 server to the new 2012 R2 server. Can i just backup the DHCP and then restore it on the new server.

Can i do this in production?

Comment: Yes, you can do this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, as outlined in this technet article.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495425.aspx

> This guide describes the steps for migrating existing DHCP server
>   settings to a server that is running Windows Server 2012 R2. Migration
>   documentation and tools ease the migration of server role settings and
>   data from an existing server to a destination server that is running
>   Windows Server 2012 R2. By using the tools that are described in this
>   guide to migrate a DHCP server, you can simplify migration, reduce
>   migration time, increase the accuracy of the migration process, and
>   help eliminate possible conflicts that might otherwise occur during
>   DHCP migration.